# How to encode the url from ajax return data then append to html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "get_title_list.php", //server API name
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {id: id},
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {
    if(response.length!=0)
    {
      $("#faq").html('');
      var html = '';
      $.each(response, function(index, array) {
        // fi_title:標題文字, fi_content:內容文字
        html+='<div class="content">'
          +'<table width="100%" border="0">'
            +'<tr>'
            +'<td style="width:50px;vertical-align:top;"><img src="answer_icon.jpg" style="width:20px;" /></td>'
            +'<td style="text-align:left;">'+ array['fi_content'] +'</td>'
            +'</tr>'
          +'</table>'
        +'</div>';
      });
      $("#faq").append(html); 
    }
  },
});
```

I will have content in "array['fi_content'] and in this content may have some string and with a url like below.

" Welcome to my website.Visit link. http://www.mypage.com "

In google debug mode, it will look like

```
<p>
Welcome to my website.Visit link.
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com">http://www.mypage.com</a>
</p>
```

My question is how to encode the url before append to html?
Can I use get url by href attribute and change it then append it with string ?

Comment: Do you mean adding links for all URLs in your string?

Comment: No, i mean how to find a url in ajax return data then encode it and append again.

Comment: what do you mean by `encode`, for what purpose?

Comment: for example, the url may have chinese  word, so I have to encode it.

Comment: i got this "<p>
Welcome to my website.Visit link.
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.mypage.com">http://www.mypage.com</a>
</p>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make some changes to the `href` attribute, the easiest way would be parsing it as HTML and then change the DOM. Since you are using jQuery, you can also use its parsing.

```
var content = $(array['fi_content']); // parses HTML as jQuery object.
content.find("a").each(function (_, link) {
  var href = link.getAttribute("href"); // Do not use .href as it contains parsed absolute URL instead.
  // Do any encoding you like to href here.
  link.href = href; // Set the href back to element.
});
var processedContentHtml = content.html();
// You can now concat processedContentHtml into your string.
// Ex: +'<td style="text-align:left;">'+ processedContentHtml +'</td>'
```

Comment: Can I ask another question...what if there is two or more url in array['fi_content'] ??

Comment: This solution works for each `<a href="..."></a>` tag in `array['fi_content']`.  So don't worry, everything will be fine.

Comment: sorry, I did not see you use .each .

Answer (score 0):

Replace `array['fi_content']` to this:

```
array[ 'fi_content' ].replace( /<a(\s[^>]*\s|\s)href=[\"\']([^\"\']*)[\"\']([^>]*)>/ig, function( s1, url, s2 ) {
    return '<a' + s1 + 'href="' + encode( url ) + '"' + s2 + '>';
} );
```

I don't have any idea what mean saying `encode` so I just pass url to function `encode` which you should implement by yourself.